# Drop in traffic due to HTTPS security

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, antivirus

Ours is a educational website [collegesearch.in](https://www.collegesearch.in/) which is HTTPS secured. We are loosing our desktop traffic because we get error like untrusted certificate on public domain networks and also some of the antiviruses block our website as well. There is no issue with our certificate and they are issued by CSA and are not self-signed.

We understand some of the pages may include mixed content like stuffed http links, which we identify and remove but this itself does not seem to be the reason of traffic drop.

We have 75% mobile users and only ~20% of desktop, while our competitors have 40% of desktop users and they are http websites. This makes us think that using HTTPS has become ironically a problem.

My question is What makes antiviruses block HTTPS website?

Why we get untrusted certicate error?

Anything that can help here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site collegesearch.in:

- is using a self-signed certificate and thus is not trusted by default by any browsers
- on top of this the certificate is expired
- on top of this the name in the certificate does not match the URL
- on top of that you are offering insecure ciphers

For more details see [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=collegesearch.in).

Interestingly, www.collegesearch.in is [setup in a different way](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.collegesearch.in)  although it still offers some weak ciphers.

It looks like that you are trying to deal with the badly setup collegesearch.in by redirecting users to www.collegesearch.in. But, for the redirect to work the user is first confronted with the bad certificate from collegesearch.in which he must accept before the browsers continues with the HTTP request which then results in the redirect to www.collegesearch.in. To fix this you need to have a proper certificate setup not only for www.collegesearch.in but also collegesearch.in.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I think that you have checked SSL certificate of collegesearch.in rather than www.collegesearch.in . We redirect collegesearch.in to www.collegesearch.in and if you check the report of  www.collegesearch.in it is quite good. please check: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.collegesearch.in

Comment: A redirect doesn't help you if the original site isn't trusted. In the question you put collegesearch.in - I assume that's what you are advertising?

Comment: @RahulRajput: see updated response - it looks like that you are trying to work around the bad setup of collegesearch.in by redirecting to www.collegesearch.in which will not work.